# Pthread scheduler scope variables?

Tags: linux-kernel, process-management, multithreading, thread

I read that their is 1:1 mapping of user and kernel thread in linux

What is the difference between PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS & PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM in linux if kernel is considering every thread like a process then there will not be any performance difference? Correct me I'm wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the man page:

> Linux supports PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM, but not PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS

And if you take a look at the [glibc's implementation](http://osxr.org:8080/glibc/source/nptl/pthread_attr_setscope.c?v=glibc-2.18#0041):

```
0034   /* Catch invalid values.  */
0035   switch (scope)
0036     {
0037     case PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM:
0038       iattr->flags &= ~ATTR_FLAG_SCOPEPROCESS;
0039       break;
0040 
0041     case PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS:
0042       return ENOTSUP;
0043 
0044     default:
0045       return EINVAL;
0046     }
```